# Polymer Iron-selector - Deselect the template on Save

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am having odd behavior with Polymer 1 Iron-selector

Below is my code.

```
<iron-selector selected="{{_selectedIndex}}">
<template is="dom-if" if="[[colors.length]]">
    <colors-item colors="[[colors]]"></colors-item>
</template>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{colorways}}">
    <colorway-item colorway="{{item}}"></colorway-item>
</template>
```

and in Properties selectedIndex looks like this

```
_selectedIndex: Number,
```

If I make changes and save, I want the selected to be none. How can i do this?

Comment: None as in not showing anything or "none" as a string? If prior what is the result you are currently seeing?

Comment: have you tried to set undefined of `_selectedIndex` ? after you made changes and save?  ie. `this._selectedIndex=null`